# asp.net core: Can't connect to websocket from Unity

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, unity-game-engine, websocket

I just started learning to write a server for my game with asp.net core.
I am trying to establish a websocket connection between the Unity game client and the asp.net core server.
I made a new asp.net core API project and added a new controller with this code in it.
[(The code is copied from here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
namespace LazerbaseASPNET.Controllers
{
    public class BrianWebSocketController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("/ws")]
        public async Task Get()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("WEBSOCKET!!! GET!!!    WEBSOCKET!!! GET!!!    WEBSOCKET!!! GET!!!    WEBSOCKET!!! GET!!!    ");
            if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                await Echo(webSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            }
        }

        private async Task Echo(WebSocket webSocket)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("WEBSOCKET!!! ECHO!!!!!    WEBSOCKET!!! ECHO!!!!!    WEBSOCKET!!! ECHO!!!!!    WEBSOCKET!!! ECHO!!!!!    ");
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
            {
                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
                result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            }
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs looks like this (I added app.UseWebSockets();)

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

In the Unity client I have the following code...

```
public async Task Connect () 
{      
    _socket = new ClientWebSocket();
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"ws://localhost:44348/ws");   
    Debug.Log("start connecting websocket");
    await _socket.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None);
    Debug.Log("finished connecting websocket");
    Listen();
}
```

I press the run with IIS express button in visual studio, which opens a browser window at the local server, the address is https://localhost:44348.
Then I leave that browser open and run the code above in Unity.. Unity never gets to this second debug line.. Debug.Log("finished connecting websocket");
Also in the asp.net program visual studio output window I never see the WEBSOCKET!!! GET!!! log.

I get this error in Unity

```
WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle+<ParseAndValidateConnectResponseAsync>d__28.MoveNext () (at <5a2009c85b134970925993880e2ecb2e>:0)
```

I have also tried publishing the asp.net program to azure and trying the url there, but I still never see the second debug.log in Unity.

I reckon my Unity code is fine as the same code is able to establish a socket connection and send and receive data from a node.js server I have on Heroku. I just have to change the url.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working. There were two issues

1. when I added these two attributes to my controller class with the sockets code in it, then I could successfully make a socket connection to server running locally with IIS express on my machine.

   ```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class BrianWebSocketController : ControllerBase
    {
   ```
2. It still did not work with the published version on azure however.. I searched all the options on azure and eventually found an option for websockets buried in there. It was turned *off* by default, so I turned it on and then I was able to make a connection to the server from Unity.

[image]